# how to deal with objectcontext instance has been disposed

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Charter(List<int> stateIds)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!stateIds.Any())
            {
                return Json("State list is empty", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            var states = new List<CfVersionEntities.Model.State>();
            stateIds.ForEach(id =>
            {
                using (var db = new Storage_cfEntities())
                {

                        var stateList = db.States.Where(i => i.Id == id).ToList();//get names of states with matching id and save in array named
                    if (!stateList.Any()) return;
                    var state = stateList[0];
                    states.Add(state);
                }
          });
            return !states.Any() ? Json(new List<State>(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) : Json(states, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Json(new List<State>(),
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

I have a method that accepts values from my jquery scripts which is below, the script works fine and sends the values, the values are received in my method, i have confirmed that. but when i run it i get the error :The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.... I am using the values from my jquery to loop through my database and select rows that have corresponding IDs, i am then sending this result back to another function in my jquery which creates a highchart with the values

This is my View which includes my script.

### List Of States

```
<p>
    <h2> @Html.ActionLink("Add A New State", "CreateState")</h2>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Stations)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Stations)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Update Stations", "UpdateStation", new {id = item.Id})||
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="@item.Id" value="@item.Id" class="chk" onclick="setChecked(this)"> <label >Add to Chart</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<div id="charts" style="width:100%" height="400px;"></div>



<input type="button" value="Verify Selections" onclick="submit()"/>
<input type="button" value ="View Chart" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Charter")'" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var collection = [];
    function setChecked(el) {

        var id = $(el).attr('id');
        if ($(el).is(':checked')) 
        {
            collection.push(id);
        } else {
            $.each(collection, function (item, index)
            {
                if (item === id)
                {
                    collection.splice(index, 1);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    function submit() {
        if (collection == null || collection.length < 1) {
            alert('please select at least one state.');
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/State/Charter',
            data: { stateIds: collection },
            dataType: 'application/json',
            success: function (response)
            {
                if (response.length > 0) {

                    designChart(response);
                }
            }

        });
    }

    function designChart(response)
    {
        var names = [];
        var stations = [];

        $.each(response, function (item) {
            if (item.Id > 0) {
                names.push(item.Name);
                stations.push(item.Stations);
            }
        });

        $("#charts").highcharts({
            chart:
            {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'States'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: names
            },
            yAxis:
                {
                    title:
                        {
                            text: 'Stations',
                            categories: stations
                        }
                }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You open a connection to your database for each item in your `stateIds`?

Comment: That error will happen when you try to traverse an object relation on your model that wasn't eagerly loaded when retrieved in your database connection. I suspect, from your naming convention that "Stations" is a joined table with a 1 to many relationship, and that's probably your problem. Your query is only loading up states, but your view is trying to load up information about Stations which doesn't appear to have been loaded in your query. Your database connection was closed, and when you try to enumerate "Stations" you will get this error.

Comment: This link gives some detail into the problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893352/the-objectcontext-instance-has-been-disposed-winforms-entity-framework. Not sure if you are using Entity Framework, but the concept should apply.

Comment: no, the "Stations" is just another column, forgive the naming error. The table is named States, each row in States has an Id, a string Name and an Int Stations.

Comment: Somewhere in your code, there is a traversal happening to a lazy-loaded object after your database connection has been closed. That is exactly what the error is saying. Where that is, I'm not entirely sure. That being said, your code needs some optimization: don't open a new database connection for every state ID you search for.